# Check to see if page counter has increased

Tags: macros, lists, conditionals, counters

I need to redefine the `\item` command so that in a long list the item that appears at the top of a page will behave differently. Any suggestions? My approach is to find a way to write an `\ifthenelse{test}{ }{ }` statement where the "test" checks to see if the page counter has increased. Thanks

Comment: What should happen if you have a large paragraph as part of one `\item` that flows over to the next page and the first `\item` doesn't start at the top of the text block? Or will that never happen, or you just don't care?

Comment: My items are short and so I do not have the problem of having them extend to the next page. I will need a solution to this problem will be needed if my items become longer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example appends content to `\enumerate` to keep track of `\item`s and on which page they occur using the `\label`-`\ref` system.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox,lipsum,refcount}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{enumeratecntr}
\newcommand{\setitemlabel}{\label{enum-\theenumeratecntr-\csname the\@enumctr\endcsname}}
\newcommand{\saveprevitem}{\edef\previtem{\csname the\@enumctr\endcsname}}
\patchcmd{\enumerate}% <cmd>
  {\fi}% <search>
  {\stepcounter{enumeratecntr}% New enumerate environment
   \setitemlabel\saveprevitem% Set label and save previous counter
   \let\olditem\item% Store \item
   \renewcommand{\item}{% Update \item
     \olditem\leavevmode% Set regular \item
     \setitemlabel
     % Check if on a new page
     \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{enum-\theenumeratecntr-\previtem}<
       \getpagerefnumber{enum-\theenumeratecntr-\csname the\@enumctr\endcsname}
       {\bfseries New page.} \par% Set some content to identify new page
     \fi
     \saveprevitem% Update previous counter
   }%
  \fi}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third
  \item Fourth
  \item Fifth
  \item Sixth
  \item Seventh
  \item Eighth
  \item Ninth
  \item Tenth
\end{enumerate}

\sloppy% Just for this example

\begin{enumerate}
  \item\lipsum[1]
  \item\lipsum[2]
  \item\lipsum[3]
  \item\lipsum[4]
  \item\lipsum[5]
  \item\lipsum[6]
  \item\lipsum[7]
  \item\lipsum[8]
  \item\lipsum[9]
  \item\lipsum[10]
  \item\lipsum[11]
  \item\lipsum[12]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The patch is specific to the `enumerate` environment, but can be updated to function with `itemize` as well. Additionally, the optional argument to `\item` has been removed in order to set an `\item` immediately as it appears (via `\leavevmode`).